# Is it possible to use Mahout for term extraction?

Tags: extract, mahout

Is it possible to use Apache Mahout for term extraction? The term can be words or phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a broad question. I don't think its purpose as a project directly includes term extraction, though the TF-IDF implementation probably has a lot of the pieces and building blocks that might be of use in making such an implementation.

Comment: Thank you shown. I got a similar answer from the Mahout mailing list too.

Comment: I suppose Mahout supports LDA, isnt LDA similar to term extraction?

Comment: I decided to use OpenCalais.